# Separating Results

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am using the following code as the results view for 2 quizzes. Both feed their scores into it. I am trying to make the view so that the user can see their scores for each game in a separate area, however when I run this the scores end up combining into one ie user scores 20 in game 1 and then 15 in game 2, instead of having 2 sets of scores there is 1 which has 20 as no.1 and 15 as no.2.  Any suggestions on how I can get around this?  Thanks

```
enum GameType: Int {
    case airline = 0, plane
}

struct ResultsView: View {
    
    var gameType: GameType
    var score: Int
    
    @AppStorage("1") var score0 = 0
    @AppStorage("2") var score1 = 0
    @AppStorage("3") var score2 = 0

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 12) {
            switch gameType {
            case .airline:
                Text("\(score == 0 ? "No score" : "Last game Score: \(score)")")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.red)
            case .plane:
                Text("Last Game Score: \(score)")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.blue)
            }

            VStack {
                switch gameType {
                case .airline:
                    Text("Airline Game Top Scores")
                    Text("1: \(score0)")
                    Text("2: \(score1)")
                    Text("3: \(score2)")
                case .plane:
                    Text("Plane Game Top Scores")
                    Text("1: \(score0)")
                    Text("2: \(score1)")
                    Text("3: \(score2)")
                }
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                saveScore()
            }, label: {
                Text("Save score")
            })

            Button(action: {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Text("Return to game menu")
            })
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Score", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
    
    func saveScore() {
        if score >= score0 {
            score2 = score1
            score1 = score2
            score0 = score
        } else if score >= score1 {
            score2 = score1
            score1 = score
        } else if score >= score2 {
            score2 = score
        } else {
            print("Good try")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ResultsView` only accepts one type of `GameType`, so you will only see one set of results.  Show the parent view that presents `ResultsView`.

Comment: You have two types of games but only one set high scores